# What is the source and authenticity of the narration about Abu Dharr insulting Bilal as the ‘son of the black woman’?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

Salaam Alaikum, Can you tell me the source for this Hadith is it authenticated?

> When his Arab Companion Abu Dharr called Bilal ‘son of the black woman’, the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) got angry and told him: ‘You are a man who has ignorance in him.’ Abu Dharr felt such a great remorse that he put his cheek on the ground and asked Bilal to tread on his other cheek if he’d like to.

Answer (score 3):

According to Juynboll's *Encyclopedia of Canonical Hadith*, on the authority of al-Ma'rur b. Suwayd, the *mu'ammar*:

> We passed by Abu Dharr in Rabadha...Abu Dharr said, "I had a quarrel with one of my brethren whose mother was of foreign descent, so I vilified him as [you son of a black mother]. He went to complain about me to the Prophet. When the Prophet met me (one day), he said, 'Abu Dharr, you are someone who still displays Jahiliyyah.'"

There is more, but nothing about asking Bilal to tread on his other cheek. In fact, Bilal is not specifically mentioned, but this *Encyclopedia* is mostly about the Prophet's statements, so it makes sense it would not mention Abu Dharr's act of contrition in particular. And again, Juynboll does say there are variants.

As for the source, Juynboll says the most likely common link for all the variations is al-A'mash, that is, Sulayman b. Mihran.

Comment: I just deleted my comment as even if the story was well known and wide spread the only sahih story is neither clearly saying it was Bilal with whom Abu Dharr had his differences or dispute nor that he told him "Son of a black woman" nor the story of asking "Bilal to tread his other cheek". So thanks for your post!

Comment: You make a point here that I should have mentioned: Juynboll's rendition of the hadith says only **you son of your mother**; the part about **black** mother is only in his footnotes. Unfortunately, Juynboll doesn't say where the tradition came from about being from a **black** mother. I would like to edit my answer to mention this, but I should probably say something about the connotation of **you son of your mother**, specifically, why it would be considered an insult in Abu Dharr's culture. On that point, I have no knowledge. If you have any thoughts on that, please do let me know.

Comment: Thank you for this answer very insightful brother, I believe this hadith is forged as is much of this Juynbolls works... JazakAllah

Answer (score 0):

The closest hadith I can find is recorded by **al-Bayhaqi** in **Shu`ab al-Iman**.

> عن أبي أمامة قال: عير أبو ذر بلالا بأمه، فقال: يا ابن السوداء، وإن بلالا أتى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم، فأخبره فغضب، فجاء أبو ذر ولم يشعر، فأعرض عنه النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم، فقال: ما أعرضك عني إلا شيء بلغك يا رسول الله
>
> قال:  أنت الذي تعير بلالا بأمه؟ " قال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم:  والذي أنزل الكتاب على محمد - أو ما شاء الله أن يحلف - ما لأحد علي فضل إلا بعمل، إن أنتم إلا كطف الصاع
>
> <sup>[ My own translation so treat with extreme caution as may contain mistakes and is paraphrased etc. ]</sup>
>
> Abu Umamah narrated:
>
> Abu Dharr taunted Bilal regarding his mother and said: "O son of a black woman".
> Bilal went to the Messenger of Allah ﷺ and informed him about it, so the Prophet got angry.
>
> When Abu Dharr came to the Prophet, the Prophet turned his face away from him. Abu Dharr asked: You turn away from me because of something you have heard about me, O Messenger of Allah?
>
> The Prophet said: You ridiculed Bilal about his mother? By the one who has revealed the scripture on Muhammad, no one has any superiority over another except by deeds ...
>
> <sup>— [شعب الإيمان](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31612/5223)</sup>

Its chain is **weak**.

> [image]
>
> <sup>— [Researcher's footnote](https://ia800702.us.archive.org/31/items/FP62379/gse07.pdf#page=130)</sup>

However authentic ahadith supporting its general meaning exist. For example in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/80) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1661a).